# Raspberry Pi 4b will not boot/reboot WITH monitor connected

Tags: pi-4, display, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 4b that will NOT boot/reboot with a monitor (either HDMI or old digital computer monitor through HDMI to 9 pin connector) connected. If the monitor is disconnected the booting process starts immediately. The monitor can then be reconnected and it works fine. If a monitor is not connected at all and the system is rebooted via ssh connection it also works fine.

**Details**

I have two Raspberry PI 4b's one works fine, the other has this problem.

1. The "good unit" one works fine in all conditions with any combinations of cables and power supplies and with three different SD cards.
2. The "problem unit" will not boot/reboot with a monitor plugged in regardless of cables, power supplies, or SD card unless the monitor is disconnected or the reboot is begun via ssh. Once the booting is started, the monitor can be reconnected and it works fine once it boots with all combinations of cables, power supplies and SD Cards.

I've tried every combination of factory supplies, cables, monitors, and SD cards with each 4b and results are the same.

- The Good Unit is board c03111 with bootloader c305221a Sep 3 2020.
- The Problem Unit is board c03112 with bootloader 778c182c 2022/03/10. (Note - I updated the boot loader earlier this year before I localized the problem thinking is may be the problem. - The problem was there with the original bootloader, which unfortunately, I don't know its previous version.
- I've tried "booting" without an SD card -
  -- the LED lights on the Good Unit start with a red LED and immediately gets a green LED with info on the display showing startup and that it cannot find an SD card.
  -- the LED lights on the Problem Unit start with a red LED and will not flash the green LED until the monitor is disconnected. It will then mimic the GU.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.